# Is it possible to combine SELECT function with LAST function in SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Need help figuring out how to use the LAST function to narrow down my database query to the latest entry with specific filters.

I'm working in MS Access to test the queries.

Question: I am trying to filter my database with a simple query to narrow down my data to only items which match a specific `WorkOrder` and `Run`.

**Code:**

```
SELECT *
FROM DataPoints
WHERE (((DataPoints.[WorkOrder])=[WO2]) AND ((DataPoints.[RunNumber])=6))
```

The above code works great.  Next, I want to obtain only the data from the latest entry.  I believe I need to incorporate the `LAST()` function, but can't figure out how.

Ideas?  I would appreciate it. Thanks.

[image: Sample data snippet].

Comment: How do you know which entry is the latest? It would probably help if you could share sample data and expected output.

Comment: I am hoping to use the latest RunTime.  Sorry, I should have included that before.  I added a link to a snippet of the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could order the results by the date & time fields and select only the top 1, e.g.:

```
select top 1 t.*
from datapoints t
where t.workorder = [WO2] and t.runnumber = 6
order by t.rundate desc, t.runtime desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a correlated subquery wit a `NOT EXISTS` condition to filter only the latest record, like:

```
SELECT dp.*
FROM DataPoints AS dp
WHERE (
    ((dp.[WorkOrder])=[WO2]) 
    AND ((dp.[RunNumber])=6)
    AND (
        NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT 1 
            FROM DataPoints AS dp1
            WHERE (
                ((dp1.[WorkOrder]) = (dp.[WorkOrder])) 
                AND ((dp1.[RunNumber]) = (dp1.[RunNumber]))
                AND ((dp1.[RunTime]) > (dp.[RunTime]))
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you GMB.  This code works good.  While I'm not using it for this particular issue, it actually answers a big question that I have coming down the line.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to include a unique key to identify the record by utilizing the `LAST()` function it would make this really easy.

The example I provided shows how you would do this should you wish to still use the `LAST()` function.  In order for my example to work I created a Primary Key in your `DataPoints` Table and named it `PrimaryWO_Key`.

**First**: Create a Query to obtain the unique key for the last record inserted/created.  In my example I named this Query `Last_WorkOrderPrimaryKey`.

**Second**: Create your Results Query to use the Query we just created.  I named this Query 'Last Work Order Record'.

Any saved Query in Access can be used as if it was an 'Actual' Table.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Beware of using `first` or `last` on an unordered dataset as, without an `order by` clause, you cannot rely on the order in which records will be served up when the query is executed - this is noted in the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/first-last-functions-acd76019-c37f-432d-9807-4fc63cac1db5). Aside, why use a cartesian product over an inner join?

Comment: I personally wouldn't use this function in this manner though I designed the answer around the question and made use of the Last function.  When working with a single table of data in ACCESS this will always work.  If this were to include more tables an ORDER BY clause would be necessary.

Comment: Also... since our Saved Query returns a single row there was no need to Join the tables but would work the same.  I have found that the way I work in ACCESS is very different from how I work in Oracle and not joining these tables is just one example.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful!  I went ahead and avoided the Last function, as suggested, and used Lee Mac's solution with the primary keys.